# Specify default value for collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In scala, is there an idiomatic way to specify default value for collections when it's empty?

For `Option`s, you could use `.getOrElse`.
I'm thinking something like below:

```
Seq().ifEmpty(Seq("aa", "bb")) // Seq("aa", "bb")
Seq("some", "value").ifEmpty(Seq("aa", "bb")) // Seq("some", "value")
```

Comment: Does not `Option` give you this behaviour?

Comment: `Option` does give you this behavior, I'm looking for something similar for collections.

Comment: IMHO `Option` is better way to provide default value for whole object. `Option(Seq("some", "value")).filter(_.nonEmpty).getOrElse(Seq("aa", "bb"))`.

Comment: @Yeonho no, there are no such thing, at least for Seq (Map has ability to set default value for key/value)

Comment: A better way is to use a type which guarantees that collection is not empty, for example [`NonEmptyList`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/#scalaz.NonEmptyList)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way for scala (without scalaz) seems to be:

```
Option(list).filter(_.nonEmpty).getOrElse(List(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this OK?

```
scala> val seq = "ABCDEFG".toIndexedSeq
seq: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)

scala> seq(3)
res0: Char = D

scala> val ept = Seq.empty[Char]
ept: Seq[Char] = List()

scala> ept(3)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:51)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:83)
  ... 32 elided

scala> ept.orElse(seq)(3)
res3: Char = D
```

OR

```
scala> ept.applyOrElse(3, "abcdef")
res4: Char = d
```

Comment: `List(1).orElse(List(1,2,3))(2)` will give you `3` instead of `IndexOutOfBound`, so it acts like default value for collection's elements but not collection itself

Answer (score 0):

You may try scalaz's `toNel` (to **N**on-**e**mpty **l**ist) - it will give you `Some(collection)` for non-empty collection and `None` for empty collection, so you can do `list.toNel.getOrElse(List(1))` :

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> List(1, 2, 3).toNel
res8: Option[scalaz.NonEmptyList[Int]] = Some(NonEmptyList(1, 2, 3))

scala> nil[Int].toNel
res9: Option[scalaz.NonEmptyList[Int]] = None
```

`nil[Int]` means `List[Int]()` here.

Src: http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/6.0/doc.sxr/scalaz/ListW.scala.html